# EF code first custom table issue deleting on cascade with foreign key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, cascade

So, I am working with an entity called MyEntity in my database. There is also another table which shows details for the MyEntity entity, called MyEntityDetail. The relationship is one to many, i.e. a MyEntity record can have several MyEntityDetails. However, the DB table is poorly designed and I cannot change this. The table definition is the following:

```
MyEntity:
myentity_id (PK)
property_1
property_2

MyEntityDetail:
myentity_id (nullable)
property_3
property_4
```

I am working with EF and code first. My class definition is as follows:

```
public class MyEntity
{
    public int EntityId {get; set;}
    public int PropertyOne {get; set;}
    public int PropertyTwo {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<MyEntityDetail> SomeDetails {get; set;}
}

public class MyEntityDetail
{
    public int EntityId {get; set;}
    public int PropertyThree {get; set;}
    public int PropertyFour {get; set;}
}
```

The way these classes are being mapped to their respective tables on the context initialization is the following:

```
        public MyEntityMapping(string schema = "dbo")
        {
            ToTable(schema + ".MyEntity");
            HasKey(e => e.EntityId);
            Property(e => e.EntityId).HasColumnName("myentity_id").IsRequired();
            Property(e=> e.PropertyOne).HasColumnName("property_1").IsRequired();
            Property(e=> e.PropertyTwo).HasColumnName("property_2").IsRequired();
            HasMany(e=> e.MyEntityDetail)
                .WithOptional()
                .HasForeignKey(e=> e.EntityId)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }

            public MyEntityDetailMapping(string schema = "dbo")
            {
                ToTable(schema + ".MyEntityDetail");
                HasKey(e => new {e.EntityId, e.PropertyFour});
                Property(e => e.EntityId).HasColumnName("myentity_id").IsRequired();
                Property(e=> e.PropertyThree).HasColumnName("property_3").IsRequired();
                Property(e=> e.PropertyFour).HasColumnName("property_4").IsRequired();
            }
```

What I am trying to accomplish is to query certain selected entities from the MyEntity table and delete them alongside with their respective MyEntityDetails. However I am running into several issues. The way I do it is the following:

1. Query from the MyEntity table and get a list of several EntityId's
2. Query from the MyEntityDetails table and get a list of several MyEntityDetail objects.
3. Erase the objects obtained in step 1 by performing: `MyContext.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Deleted;`
4. Erase the objects obtained in step 2 as done in step 3.

However, the issue is that a MyEntity can have several MyEntityDetails which are exactly the same. So, when EF tries to attach the object based on the primary key defined in the mapping, I get an exception that states that  another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value.

My idea is to change the mapping of the entities somehow and allow the on cascade delete in order to query only for the MyEntity entities and perform the deletion which would also delete the related MyEntityDetail objects. However, I do not know how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm afraid you're lost here as far as EF is concerned. EF needs a unique key anyhow. If the details aren't even unique by Id + other properties there's no way to get this done. Can't you even add an identity column to the details?

Comment: I cannot touch the database design in any way.

Comment: You could do an ExecuteSQLCommand. http://www.binaryintellect.net/articles/fbc96859-8a31-4735-baeb-7adcbc521b30.aspx